# How to create a variable and apply it to a column?

Tags: r, dplyr, bioinformatics

This is kind of a two part question. I have a dataset that I am attempting to add select column together, but I also want to alter the data so it is a bit easier to add. Here is an example of my data set. The data set is called ChrData

```
ChrData
  Chr location sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
1 1 34234 ./. 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/0
2 1 5677876 0/1 1/1 1/2 0/0 1/1
3 1 75424 ./. ./. 1/1 0/1 0/0
4 1 98654 1/1 0/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
5 1 4534 1/1 0/1 ./. 0/0 2/2
```

So what I would like to do is set

```
./. = 0 
0/0 = 0
0/1 = 1
1/2 = 1
1/1 = 2
2/2 = 2
```

And then add columns:

```
ChrData$sample1 + ChrData$sample2 + ChrData$sample4
```

and also:

```
ChrData$sample3 + ChrData$sample5
```

and then create a two new columns with this data. I am just not sure how to get R to recognize the new variables and then apply them to each cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *dplyr*:

```
# reproducible data
ChrData <- read.table(text = "
Chr location sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
1 1 34234 ./. 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/0
2 1 5677876 0/1 1/1 1/2 0/0 1/1
3 1 75424 ./. ./. 1/1 0/1 0/0
4 1 98654 1/1 0/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
5 1 4534 1/1 0/1 ./. 0/0 2/2", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

# make lookup map
MAP <- setNames(c(0,0,1,1,2,2), c("./.","0/0","0/1","1/2","1/1","2/2"))

# convert using MAP, then rowsums per sample groups
ChrData <- ChrData %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("sample")), .funs = funs(MAP[ . ])) %>% 
  mutate(s124 = rowSums(.[ c("sample1","sample2","sample4") ]),
         s35 = rowSums(.[ c("sample3","sample5") ]))

ChrData
#   Chr location sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 s124 s35
# 1   1    34234       0       1       2       1       0    2   2
# 2   1  5677876       1       2       1       0       2    3   3
# 3   1    75424       0       0       2       1       0    1   2
# 4   1    98654       2       1       2       0       0    3   2
# 5   1     4534       2       1       0       0       2    3   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Top of mind this basic function and then apply will do job assuming all are character in sample columns

```
 replacement<-function(x){
 x=replace(x,which(x=='./.'),0) 
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/0'),0)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/1'), 1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/2'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/1'),2)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='2/2'),2)
}

ChrData=apply(ChrData,2,replacement)
ChrData[,3:7]=apply(ChrData,2,as.numeric)

ChrData$Sum1=ChrData$sample1 + ChrData$sample2 + ChrData$sample4
ChrData$Sum2=ChrData$sample3 + ChrData$sample5
```

Comment: I think this will do most of it! Do you know how to add the samples together? Would I use something like rowsum?

Comment: Updated .. i guess that sum will work, below one will do too

Comment: This is a late comment, but I didn't get to fully test what you wrote until I had my full dataset ...and wow it is fast. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Thanks ... apply is usually really fast always, may be an upvote on the solution?

Comment: Not high enough level yet.. sorry